# Why can't I specify column width in MS SQL?

Tags: sql-server, create-table

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Station
(StationCode    CHAR(10) NOT NULL,      
StationName CHAR(20)        NOT NULL,
Distance    int(5)      NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PKStation    PRIMARY KEY (StationCode)   )
```

It returned error:

> Msg 2716, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>       Column, parameter, or variable #3: Cannot specify a column width on data type int.

In my University textbook, the example is able to specify column width for INTEGER
TQVM if someone can answer

Comment: Does your textbook cover *Microsoft SQL Server* or *MySQL*? Those are two *very* different products with their own SQL dialects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you cannot specify a column `width` on data type `int`.

`Int` `datatype` does not have `length`.

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE Station 
(
 StationCode CHAR(10) NOT NULL,      
 StationName CHAR(20)        NOT NULL,
 Distance    int NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT  PKStation PRIMARY KEY (StationCode)   
)
```

Comment: Then solution is to drop and create the Table? god damn MSSQL!

Answer (score 4):

The SQL ANSI standard integer data type does not allow a precision specification.  It is a 4-byte signed integer, allowing values from -2147483648 to 2147483647.  Database products besides SQL Server may provide non-ANSI proprietary extensions that allow a precision specification.